# What does W stand for in the W entangled state?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, resource-request, history

For the $|W_3\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(|001\rangle+|010\rangle+|100\rangle)$, what does W stand for? Does it refer to an author name? Anyone knows a reference? Thanks

Comment: Wikipedia entry doesn't know either https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/W_state

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently $\vert W \rangle$ was first reported (and the naming convention first adopted) by Dür, Vidal and Cirac in this [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0005115) on May 26, 2000 (version 1 of 2).

This is supported by the footnote on page 4 of this [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9908073) on June 25, 2000 (version 3 of 3, this footnote did not appear in the earlier versions), which states (in part)

> Very recently Dürr [*sic*], Vidal, and Cirac (LANL eprint quantph/0005115)
>   have found a tripartite pure state of 3 qubits which is stochastically
>   incomparable with the GHZ state.

Dür, Vidal and Cirac don't explicitly ascribe any special significance to the notational choice $\vert W \rangle$, so it seems that only the authors could say with any confidence whether $W$ has any significance.

**Edit:** The lead author's first initial is W. (for Wolfgang), which is plausible motivation for the notation $\vert W \rangle$, but I'm not aware of any evidence to support this.

Comment: I, for one, really appreciate the lack of DVC notation - I struggle enough with GHZ, trying to misspell it as GHC or something else about half of the time :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did search DVC paper and could not find an explanation. I will wait to see if any other information pops up. If not, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Anecdotally, I was originally told that the three peaks of the letter W stood for the positions of the single '1' in each of the standard basis components.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap ha! We could write the $|W\rangle$ state as the $|Ш\rangle$ state!